# Will the openid scope "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.me" be affected by the Google+ shutdown?

Tags: scope, google-api, google-oauth, google-plus, google-openidconnect

I would like to know if the following scope URI would be affected by the Google+ shutdown or not.

- https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.me

This scope is named "openid" in the "OAuth consent screen" tab of Google API Console and has "plus.me" in the URL.
The openid scope is default setting.

But the following URL says "only projects directly requesting the 'plus.me' scope are affected".
https://developers.google.com/+/api-shutdown

It confuses me...
Is the above scope URI affected by the Google+ shutdown?

Also I would like to confirm each of the following scopes and endpoints will whether be affected or not just in case because I'm using them on my project.

- scopes

  - https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile
  - https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email
- endpoints:

  - https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth
  - https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/token

Will the above scopes and endpoints be affected?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

> I would like to know if the following scope URI would be affected by the Google+ shutdown or not.
>
> - https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.me

Note: This is not a uri it is a scope.  The scope is being shutdown.  You will not be able to use this scope when authenticating users to Google.

**What are scopes**

Different pieces of user information are often stored across a number of online resources. Users may upload and store photos with a service like Flickr, keep digital files on Dropbox, and store contacts and events in Google Calendar or on Facebook.

Often, new applications will want to make use of the information that has already been created in an online resource. To do so, the application must ask for authorization to access this information on a user's behalf. Scopes define the specific actions applications can be allowed to do on a user's behalf.

**Shutdown what?**

The documentation for the [API-shutdown](https://developers.google.com/+/api-shutdown) is not very good and can be a little confusing.

> Beginning March 7, all OAuth token requests with scopes starting with "plus." (i.e. "plus.me", "plus.login", "plus.profile.emails.read", etc) will fail upon request, and may start to intermittently fail as early as February 15, 2019.

This being any scope starting with the word plus.  If we check [Google scopes](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/googlescopes)  This gives us the following.

[image]

So yes https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.me is being shut down the others you have listed are not.

Comment: When I mouseover on the "openid" word in "Scopes for Google APIs" section in the "OAuth consent screen" tab on Google API Console, I can see the tooltip that says "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.me". Does this mean that the "openid" scope is equal to "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.me"? If so, will I need to delete the "openid" scope from my source code by February 15?

Comment: openid scope is the scope for open id connect it will not be going away.  If your code includes profile or open id scopes these are not going away.

Comment: @DalmTO we are using userinfo.email scope and I came to know it has plus.me scope dependency. I am using https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v2/userinfo API to get the user details (email, name and picture), will this be affected? What are all the details I will get from this API after Google+ API shutdown (with only userinfo.email scope).

Comment: **Userinfo.email** returns the users email address.  **profile** should be the same as the old **https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.me** which gave you access to the basic user profile data.   Where they are storing user profile data now i am not sure.  You can test out the response here https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground/

Comment: Currently googleapis.com/oauth2/v2/userinfo API returns "family_name, name, picture, email, given_name, id, verified_email" when authenticated using **userinfo.email** scope. Will it return the same user details even after G+ API shutdown?